# Skip lines in a file and print remaining lines

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file called patient.txt which has a list of dna sequences. I want to skip the first three line in this data file. Using the code below prints every line.

```
def read_patient_data(file):
    file=open('patient.txt')
    for aline in file:
        return aline
```

Comment: Your code simply returns the first line of the file, or the fourth if you skip the first 3.

Comment: I recommend calling `next(file)` as many times as you want, _then_ do your loop